# How to add 5 days with current date and format the output in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am facing problem to format the output as days/mon/years i.e ( 25/08/2019) when I add 5 days with the current date in momentjs.

```
console.log( moment().add(5, 'days').calendar());
```

Output:

```
Sunday at 8:30 PM
```

But when I add 10 days i.e:

```
console.log( moment().add(10, 'days').calendar());
```

Output:

```
08/30/2019
```

I need the output for

```
moment().add(5, 'days').calendar()
```

as

```
25/08/2019
```

I will highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use format method of moment js

```
moment().add(5, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 3):

The `moment.calendar` [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) states that:

> Calendar will format a date with different strings depending on how close to referenceTime's date (today by default) the date is.

You can use `moment().add(5, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY')` to achieve what you want.

If you still want to use the *calendar method*, we can see in the documentation that from version **2.10.5** you can pass a format parameter:

```
moment().add(5, 'days').calendar(null, {
    sameDay: '[Today]',
    nextDay: '[Tomorrow]',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: '[Yesterday]',
    lastWeek: '[Last] dddd',
    sameElse: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment's provide a day name (`Sunday`)in range of `-6 to 6`,
If you add 6 days from the current day it will be

```
moment().add(6, 'days').calendar();
// "Monday at 8:17 PM"
```

If you add -6 days from current day it will be

```
moment().add(-6, 'days').calendar();
// "Last Wednesday at 8:17 PM"
```

It will give you name of day when you add up to +6 to -6, If you pass more than 6 it returns the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format

If you add 7 days from the current day it will be

```
moment().add(7, 'days').calendar();
// "08/27/2019"
```

If you add -7 days from current day it will be

```
moment().add(-7, 'days').calendar();
// "08/13/2019"
```

Back to your query...You only need a date in the format of `DD/MM/YYYY`, So you just need to use `.format()` method instead of `.calender()`

```
moment().add(6, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```